# SQL Server 2012 : alternative to XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have been tasked with reworking a set of existing legacy queries. The main problem I can find is they all use `XML PATH()` to make updates to various temp tables before returning the results.

It breaks down like so, we create a temp table with the basic information as distinct values.

```
OwnerId | FName | LName | Pets
--------+-------+-------+-------
PA1234  | Greg  | Brady |
ZB0013  | Peter | Brady |
QX9999  | Bobby | Brady |
```

Then this table needs to be updated from a very large table - several million records. That tables looks something like this:

```
PetId | OwnerId | PetType
------+---------+-----------
100   | PA1234  | cat
101   | PA1234  | dog, bird
103   | PA1234  | gerbil
104   | ZB0013  | fish
105   | QX9999  | dog, cat
106   | QX9999  | dog, bird
107   | AA5555  | snake
```

The expected results would look something like this:

```
OwnerId | FName | LName | Pets
--------+-------+-------+-------------------------
PA1234  | Greg  | Brady | cat; dog, bird; gerbil
ZB0013  | Peter | Brady | fish
QX9999  | Bobby | Brady | dog, cat; dog, bird
```

The query as it stands yields the desired results but takes **FOREVER**. 100 records takes almost 5 minutes to return results, which seems crazy to me.

```
UPDATE #Temp 
SET Pets = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + P1.PetType
                  FROM Pet_Table P1 
                  WHERE P1.OwnerID = OuterT.OwnerId
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM #Temp OuterT
```

I feel like `COALESCE` would be faster but can't figure out how to make it work in this instance, possibly a CTE, I am looking for any suggestions.

Thanks and let me know if more information is needed or I need explain things better.

Comment: Have you made sure that the FOX XML PATH is really the problem by looking at plans? Do you have appropriate indexes on the other tables?

Comment: @pmbAustin I am positive the FOR XML PATH is the problem. I run the query w/o XML PATH and it takes ~5 seconds. With XML PATH it takes 5 min.

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: I'm going to agree with @pmbAustin here, as I have made extensive use of XML path in the past with amazing performance. If the temp table is large, perhaps you should have your script index that temp table? Without any indexing, you _are_ going to have performance issues. Alternatively, you can use a permanent table to hold this data and make sure that it is indexed properly.

Comment: Unfortunately while I have access to the execution plan I cannot post it due to corporate policies. If there is something specific I should look for I that would be great. I know that is no help at all - sorry

Comment: What are all the indexes available on that table, Pet_Table and OwnerId column? What is total row counts? Is there any insert/Update triggers, Constraints on that table?

Comment: @pmbAustin you were correct, while the tables in question were indexed, the indexing was not appropriate for the query at hand. The query now runs in less than 5 seconds, which also seems crazy but the results are correct. Is it possible to give comments the accepted mark?

Comment: I've pulled my comment out as an answer, as you cannot 'accept' comments... glad you resolved the problem!

Comment: I will rewrite query to avoid distinct.for 100 -150 record,I won't create index if that index is only helpful in this query and it has no use in other query.I think just avoiding DISTINCT for 100-150 record in update will be fast enough.And If any index which is helpful in other query also then its welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made sure that the FOX XML PATH is really the problem by looking at plans? Do you have appropriate indexes on the other tables?

FOR XML PATH is generally highly performant and I've never seen it result in a degredation of the scope you've identified here. I'd look instead at the plans, and look deeper into what indexes are (or aren't) being used, and look to see if tweaking an index (adding INCLUDE columns) or adding a new index might resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Five minutes for 100 records is too slow.  I suspect that you may never get the performance that you really want.  But, indexes will help.

First, you need to phrase the query correctly.  You need to specify `OuterT` in `UPDATE` -- because the two references to `#Temp` are different.  Your version is essentially doing a `CROSS JOIN`.

```
UPDATE OuterT 
    SET Pets = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + P1.PetType
                      FROM Pet_Table P1 
                      WHERE P1.OwnerID = OuterT.OwnerId
                      FOR XML PATH('')
                     ), 1, 1, '')
    FROM #Temp OuterT;
```

Then, you want indexes.  For this query:  `Pet_Table(OwnerId, PetType)`.

Also, if you can get rid of the `SELECT DISTINCT` then that would also help a bit.